# Centering DatePicker inside a section

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, swiftui, datepicker

[image]

Hello! I am trying to center the `DatePicker` inside the `Section` in SwiftUI. The screenshot shows the current display and desired display.

I've attempted the following and it doesn't seem to work:

- putting DatePicker in VStack with .alignment as centered,
- using .frame(alignment: .center) on the section,
- and attempting to place center decorators to the DatePicker itself.

The first 2^ center the text within the section, but not the actual DatePicker object itself on the screen.

An explanation on how to do this, and what to know for future cases like these would be super helpful. Thank you!

```
        NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section {
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    
                DatePicker("Please enter a time", selection: $wakeUpTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                    .labelsHidden()
                }
            } header: {
                Text("When do you want to wake up?")
                    .font(.headline)
            }
            .frame(alignment: .center)
            

        .navigationTitle("BetterRest")
        .toolbar {
            Button("Calculate", action: calculateBedtime)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `HStack` with two `Spacer` to acomplish this output in SwiftUI.

```
NavigationView {
    Form {
        Section {
            HStack{ //Convert to HStack
                Spacer() //add this
                DatePicker("Please enter a time", selection: $wakeUpTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                    .labelsHidden()
                Spacer() // add this
            }
        } header: {
            Text("When do you want to wake up?")
                .font(.headline)
        }
        .frame(alignment: .center)
        .navigationTitle("BetterRest")
        .toolbar {
            Button("Calculate", action: calculateBedtime)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was intending to do! Thank you so much for explaining a strategy!

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section {
                DatePicker("Please enter a time",
                           selection: $wakeUpTime,
                           displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
            } header: {
                Text("When do you want to wake up?")
                    .font(.headline)
            }
            .frame(alignment: .center)
            .navigationTitle("BetterRest")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Calculate") {
                    print("Calculate")
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! This certainly looks better, so it does accomplish my ultimate goal of a better UI. This makes me suspect perhaps there's not as flexible of a way to center the DatePicker itself within a section; this one right-aligns automatically because the label is shown and is left aligned.